# Check sopcast is installed, but it does not work

Tags: android, video-streaming

I'm all started a few weeks and update an application own, trying to learn as much as I can.

But I have a problem. This code works in xmtv player, but sopcast not working, sees the sopcast not installed.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.sopcast.android","org.sopcast.android"));
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
            if (activities != null && activities.size() > 0) {


                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/253035")));



            }
            else {






                final Toast tag = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Te rog Instaleaza Playerul Necesar pentru a putea vizualiza canalul dorit!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                tag.show();

                new CountDownTimer(9000, 1000)
                {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {tag.show();}
                    public void onFinish() {tag.show();}

                }.start();








                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.sopcast.org/download/android.html")));




            }
```

Comment: i don't think your component name is correct

Comment: much easier is to call startActivity and to catch the exception in case the activity is not found